# Browsermob proxy server crashes websites

Tags: selenium, browsermob

trying to use browsermob proxy server by falling code:

```
    final int port = 9000;
        server  = new ProxyServer(port);
        server.start();         
        final DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, server.seleniumProxy());         
        setName("test");
        FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ff21\\firefox.exe"));
        File profileDir = new File("C:\\Users\\arno\\Documents\\profiles\\firefox21.default");
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDir);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile, dc);//;
        server.newHar("monitis");
```

but it crashes the website: see the [capture](http://screencast.com/t/07QAolz4RfF) .

I'm using the fallowing code to find out what is going on(getting the url and the http status )

```
Har har = server.getHar();

            for(HarEntry entry : har.getLog().getEntries()){
                System.out.println(entry.getRequest().getUrl() +": " + entry.getResponse().getStatus());
            }
```

and it gives this result:

```
mysite/files/js/numeral.min.js: 200
mysite/js/94842541.js: 200
mysite/files/css/page-home.min.css?v=6: -999
mysite/files/css/ui.min.css?v=18: -999
mysite/files/js/ui.min.js?also=jquery.selectric.min.js,jquery.checkradios.min.js,index.min.js&v=53: -999
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the non-deprecated `BrowserMobProxyServer` class instead of the legacy `ProxyServer` implementation. Make sure you're using the latest version of BMP and the `browsermob-core-littleproxy` module as well.

Comment: latest version does not work with the selenium 2.45 an ff 21

Answer (score 0):

it turned out, that in Firefox settings, in network settings tab, I need to set up the option **"auto detect proxy server for this network"**